# ¿Como duplico Paneles o Creo Nuevos Paneles?

Tags: c#

Tengo un formulario, en ese formulario quiero comprar los productos comprados y sus caracteristicas en diferente paneles, osea, cada vez que agregue un nuevo articulo quiero que se cree un nuevo panel. He intentado instanciar un panel nuevo y darle las caracteristicas de uno ya creado, pero al darle Location se mueve el que que ya tenia, y no el nuevo que cree.

Creo que lo que necesito es un for each, pero no se como implementarlo.

Lo que trato de hacer es.
Mi panel ya creado se llama item, el item tiene 2 textbox, 1 textbox para articulo, y otro para la caracteristica (Grande, mediano, pequeño).

```
Panel myNuevoPanel = new Panel();
myNuevoPanel = item;
myNuevoPanel.Location = new Point(40, 50);
```

Cuando trato de hacer eso se mueve mi item, y no se mueve el nuevo panel que trato de crear.

Answer (score 0):

Es por esta línea:

```
myNuevoPanel = item;
```

Si lo que quieres hacer es crear un panel igual al anterior debes clonarlo, o copiar las propiedades del panel anterior al nuevo panely agregar los controles que lleva dentro del panel.

```
myNuevoPanel.Size = item.Size;
myNuevoPanel.Location = item.Location;
// etc
```

Recuerda que al ser tipos por referencia, no estás copiando realmente el valor de item, sino asignando la referencia, y por lo tanto myNuevoPanel es una referencia a item.

**Edit:** otra cosa que puedes hacer es un UserControl o control de usuario, que ya tenga dentro el textbox, así, en vez de crear un nuevo panel en tu código, creas un nuevo control del tipo que diseñaste, sino va a ser un show estar creando un panel nuevo y los controles de adentro.

Comment: Entonces tendria que copiar cada una de las propiedades de mi panel item?

Me aparecerian los textboxt o labels de mi panel item?

Comment: No, los TextBox y controles dentro del panel no se copian